# How to get the first 100 lines of a file on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a huge (~6 GB) file on Amazon S3 and want to get the first 100 lines of it without having to download the whole thing. Is this possible?

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
aws cp s3://foo/bar - | head -n 100
```

But this takes a while to execute. I'm confused -- shouldn't `head` close the pipe once it's read enough lines, causing `aws cp` to crash with a BrokenPipeError before it has time to download the entire file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the Range HTTP header in a GET request, you can retrieve a specific range of bytes in an object stored in Amazon S3. (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html)

if you use aws cli you can use `aws s3api get-object --range bytes=0-xxx`, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html

It is not exactly as a number of lines but should allow you to retrieve your file in part so avoid downloading the full object